# MySQL select max date or null date

Tags: mysql, sql

I would to select the max date or null but it shows a error message.

> Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=IS;, CASE WHEN MAX(DATE;CONCAT, DRIVER=3.64.114

The original table is

```
Employee code           resignation date
001                     1/2/2013
001                     1/5/2014
001                     null
002                     10/10/2000
```

should be show

```
EMPLOYEE_CODE           RESIGNATION_DATE
001                     null
002                     10/10/2000
```

this is my query

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_CODE, 
       CASE 
           WHEN MAX(RESIGNATION_DATE IS NULL)= 0 
           THEN MAX(RESIGNATION_DATE) 
       END AS DATE
FROM MT_EMPLOYEE_CONTRACT
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_CODE;
```

Can Anyone find out what is the problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can Anyone find out what is the problem?

In this condition :

```
MAX(RESIGNATION_DATE IS NULL)= 0
```

you are comparing `MAX(NULL)=0` as `RESIGNATION_DATE IS NULL`

Your query should be :

```
select emp_code, res_date /* first select null emp_code*/
From Table_name
where res_date IS NULL group by emp_code
UNION 
select emp_code, MAX(res_date ) /* select max from non - null emp_code*/
From Table_name
where emp_code NOT IN 
     (select emp_code From Table_name 
      where res_date IS NULL) 
group by emp_code
```

**EDIT**

```
select DISTINCT emp_code, res_date /* first select null emp_code*/
From Table_name
where res_date IS NULL 
UNION 
select emp_code, MAX(res_date ) /* select max from non - null emp_code*/
From Table_name
where emp_code NOT IN 
     (select emp_code From Table_name 
      where res_date IS NULL) 
group by emp_code
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I try to use the query. For the 1st part to select null EMPLOYEE_CODE still display the error message when added "group by EMPLOYEE_CODE". however second part is fine.

Comment: is the error message same which you posted in question or is it a different one?? `DISTINCT` would help you if error is coming..please see the **edit** query and lemme know if it helps!!! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is solved. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try to use a combination of [NULLIF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) and [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) functions .

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_CODE, NULLIF(MAX(IFNULL(RESIGNATION_DATE,0)),0)
FROM MT_EMPLOYEE_CONTRACT
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_CODE;
```